Guidewire ContactManager: One field in contact not being updated when updating by API call
While attempting to update a particular field in a contact in Guidewire ContactManager using the API, the field is not being updated.  Other fields however are being updated.  Example API call info, using Postman:
HTTP method: PATCH; URI: http://localhost:8290/ab/rest/contact/v1/contacts/h2mem:S3U0K_7cuIgA5ZqjRU_qG (port 8290 since I am in TestServer mode; h2mem:S3U0K_7cuIgA5ZqjRU_qG is the id of the contact being updated, obtained from a search call)
body:
{
"data": {
"attributes": {
"name":"TestVendor7890",
"officeType_Ext": {
"code": "government"
},
"taxId": "27-1111111"
}
}
}
Yes, I have set the userid and password in Basic Auth.  I am sending the body raw in JSON format, settings in Postman made.
So TestVendor789 is an ABCompanyVendor.  Before posting this, it has no office type (officeType_Ext) specified.  officeType_Ext you can surmise based on the _Ext is a custom attribute.  We have other custom attributes and they update OK when using the API.  But alas officeType_Ext does not update.  We get a 200 as a response so the API thinks everything is fine.  It should be returning a 400 or something if it can't update the field.  But it isn't.
After posting the above, the name is changed to TestVendor7890 and the taxID is 27-1111111.  But the officeType_Ext value remains blank.
I've searched through the GWCC codebase looking for telltale signs of where these various fields may be getting updated.  I have even come across something that LOOKS very much like it should be doing the updates; that'd be in ABCoreCustomerAPIHandler.gs in updateContactData(...).  I tried adding code that would show that that was being invoked to do the change to the contact info but that code proved to show nothing, that the code was not being invoked.
This leaves me with 2 questions, really... when would ABCoreCustomerAPIHandler.updateContactData() ever get invoked anyway, but more to the point, how are contacts getting updated by calls to the update contact API in the first place?  Is the update of contact info being handled by reflection in some kind of esoteric class that is part of the core .jars and that isn't readily viewable by a customizer?
If anyone has ideas, please share.

What version of ContactManager is this occurring on?

Answer was found in docs.  Please see https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202407/cloudapica/cloudAPI/topics/502-ResourceProperties/10-scalar/c_scalars_in_the_schema_configuration_files.html (thanks to Martin Aavik for pointing this out to me.) but in case you can't log in, I'll post here that I had to add an entry to the ...updater.json file in order for the field to be updatable.  This appears to have been necessary because the field in question uses an enum to represent the applicable values and it seems that in that case, the updater file has to be edited to include this.
File name: contact_ext-1.0.updater.json
File content:
{
  "schemaName": "ext.contact.v1.contact_ext-1.0",
  "combine": [
    "ext.common.v1.common_ext-1.0",
    "gw.content.ab.contact.v1.contact_content-1.0"
  ],
  "updaters": {
    "ABContact": {
      "properties": {
        "paymentAvailability_Ext": {
          "path": "ABContact.PaymentAvailability_Ext",
          "valueResolver": {
            "typeName": "TypeKeyValueResolver"
          }
        },
        "vendorPayInactiveReason_Ext": {
          "path": "ABContact.VendorPayInactiveReason_Ext",
          "valueResolver": {
            "typeName": "TypeKeyValueResolver"
          }
        },
        "officeType_Ext": {
          "path": "ABContact.OfficeType_Ext",
          "valueResolver": {
            "typeName": "TypeKeyValueResolver"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


"officeType_Ext": {
          "path": "ABContact.OfficeType_Ext",
          "valueResolver": {
            "typeName": "TypeKeyValueResolver"
          }
        }

is the new JSON added to the file that allowed the field to be updated.

Based on the information you provided (and other questions you asked in the past), I am assuming you are on a cloud version of ContactManager and using one of their prebuilt Rest APIs (branded as Cloud APIs I believe). My best guess is that the handler class that implements this patch call is not updating the custom field in the Gosu code.
You'll first want to lookup the yaml file that defines this API and lookup the class (x-gw-apihandler) that handles the update user function. The function should be defined as a patch and have an operationId specified which tells you what function in the handler class is actually processing the API call.
My guess is that ABCoreCustomerAPIHandler is not the handler class in this case or updateContactData is not the operationId for the API method you are invoking. I would start with published-apis.yaml and hunt for the API you are invoking from that list.
The answer is somewhere in the configuration/config/integration/apis package.

Thanks for your suggestions.  Went down the suggested rabbit hole and came up with no rabbits, alas.  One thing I did was search for all instances of "operationId" in the codebase and found quite a few, none promising nor in contact_core-1.0.swagger.yaml, for instance.

The only other thing I can think of is maybe looking at one of the mapping files to see if there is anything you can change there. There should be a lot of files with the mapping.json suffix.

I'll add to Steves answer by pointing you to the Cloud API Developers Guide (requires login) where the process of adding properties to existing entities and APIs are covered thoroughly.  Please review the extensive documentation for Cloud APIs and other subjects.   https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202407/cloudapica/cloudAPI/topics/502-ResourceProperties/10-scalar/c_scalars_in_the_schema_configuration_files.html

@MartinAavik Thanks Martin.  Yes, that was very helpful.  I discovered an entry in the updater.json file for the contact API was not present.  When I added the necessary entry, lo, the updating of that field succeeded now via API call using Postman.  So, we good.
